# Getting SQL stored procedure results into data.frame format using RODBC

Tags: sql-server-2008, r, rodbc

I am using the RODBC package to query for results in my SQL server. I have a certain stored procedure written that, when executed in my SQL Server Mgmt. studio (for example), returns a table. However, when I run the query through R, it returns `character(0)`

```
# Execute command...
sqlQuery(production,"exec port.tdp_RISK2_ModelRunCompare @ModelRunId1 = 399")
```

Weird thing is... when I do something like...

```
sqlQuery(production,"exec sp_who")
```

I get a table of results...

Help?

Comment: So you a have schema in sql server named port?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.

You can try using:

```
set nocount on
```

in the MS SQL Server stored procedure so it will return just a dataset.

Regards,

Comment: Also is heavily important that the stored procedure should not print any message via the "PRINT" command.

Comment: Is like this link http://codeworkaround.tumblr.com/post/38942730894/executingcalling-a-ms-sql-stored-procedure-from

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlQuery(production,"exec port.tdp_RISK2_ModelRunCompare @ModelRunId1 = 399", errors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try writing to a new data frame.  I kept getting character(0) when I tried to overwrite an existing data frame with the sqlQuery function.